# Why are cross-domain POST requests allowed?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, csrf, same-origin-policy

I understand that best practice is to use tokens to prevent CSRF, but why do  browsers permit cross-site POST requests in the first place?  It seems like giving untrusted parties unfettered write access to your server is a bad idea.

The W3's site says that "Under the same-origin policy, cross-site sending of information is also dangerous since it enables attacks such as cross-site request forgery (CSRF) and clickjacking. The same-origin policy cannot address these security vulnerabilities in the same way it does those around receiving of information since prohibiting cross-site sending of information would prohibit cross-site hyperlinks." [1]

But this seems like a false dichotomy.  We could disallow cross-site POSTs while still allowing hyperlinks, which are GETs.

[1] https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Comment: What is "unfettered write access"?

Comment: @curiousguy the ability to make POST requests on the user's behalf

Answer (score -1):

> It seems like giving untrusted parties unfettered write access to your server is a bad idea.

I guess that would be true unless your entire business model depended on it:

- https://disqus.com [comment on this]
- http://Facebook.com [like this]
- https://twitter.com [tweet this]
- https://ads.google.com [support this]

Comment: These servers could opt-in to cross-origin POSTs, much like they do with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header